# android nkd-r5b+pelyaSDL ./configure error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: android, sdl, configure, android-ndk-r5, dosbox

I'm trying to compile Dosbox0.74 for Android with pelya's SDL port (https://github.com/pelya/commandergenius) using the new android-ndk-r5b.
Unfortunately the Dosbox ./configure script fails with:

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I already had to replace the config.sub and config.guess files with newer ones, so that the --host=arm-linux-androideabi flag get recognized properly. For build setup I used pelya's tutorial, which can be found on the github site pasted above.
Has anybody encountered similar errors/problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your environment settings may affect the build.
I encountered the same problem.  It turns out the cause is "export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'" in my .bash_profile.  NDK build script does not process color control characters I guess.
So my solution is I use "env PATH=${PATH}" to make the environment clean when I build an app.